# How to install hindi keyboard in android phone with the installation of my app in phone?

Tags: android, keyboard, hindi

I'm developing an app which shows Hindi font in it, also has an edittext to search for a string.
I need to search for Hindi text also, so wants to install a Hindi keyboard/inputMethod with the installation of my app only.
I don't want to install/use any other market apps for the Hindi keyboard.

I'm new to android, so anyone please guide me..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether their is a rigid requirement in using a "Hindi Keyboard". If so my answer becomes invalid.

But if you are OK with a different input mechanism I think you can use [transliteration](http://www.google.com/transliterate) in order to input your string. The implementation is not much complex in general cases. (No explicit idea on Hindi anyway) You have to detect the sequences of characters and replace appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

[Hindi keyboard for input values to my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015588/hindi-keyboard-for-input-values-to-my-application/21995572#21995572)

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015588/hindi-keyboard-for-input-values-to-my-application/21995572#21995572. Stop posting duplicate answer, instead post a single and give its link as a  reference wherever required.

Comment: @PareshMayani thanks for your suggestion :) You are my facebook friend, I am your fan :)